# Python - Can glob be used multiple times?

Tags: python, qgis

I want the user to process files in 2 different folders. The user does by selecting a folder for *First_Directory* and another folder for *Second_Directory*. Each of these are defined, have their own algorithms and work fine if only one directory is selected at a time. If the user selects both, only the *First_Directory* is processed.

Both also contain the glob module as shown in the simplified code which I think the problem lies. My question is: can the glob module be used multiple times and if not, is there an alternative?

```
##Test=name
##First_Directory=folder
##Second_Directory=folder

path_1 = First_Directory
path_2 = Second_Directory
path = path_1 or path_2

os.chdir(path)

def First(path_1):
output_1 = glob.glob('./*.shp')
#Do some processing

def Second(path_2):
output_2 = glob.glob('./*.shp')
#Do some other processing

if path_1 and path_2:
    First(path_1)
    Second(path_2)
elif path_1:
    First(path_1)
elif path_2:
   Second(path_2)
else:
    pass
```

Comment: @Cyber, you have just solved an annoying problem of mine. Thank you very much! If you want, you can re-post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your function to only look for `.shp` files in the path of interest. Then you can use that function for one path or both.

```
def globFolder(path):
    output_1 = glob.glob(path + '\*.shp')

path1 = "C:\folder\data1"
path2 = "C:\folder\data2"
```

Then you can use that generic function:

```
totalResults = globFolder(path1) + globFolder(path2)
```

This will combine both lists.

Answer (score 1):

I think by restructring your code can obtain your goal:

```
def First(path,check):

  if check:

     output = glob.glob(path+'./*.shp')
  #Do some processing
  else:
     output = glob.glob(path+'./*.shp')
#Do some other processing
 return output
#
#
#
 First(path_1,True)
 First(path_2,False)
```

Comment: Interesting method, I will give this a try aswell. Thank you.